# Firestore - Combine documents from two different collection - React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, react-typescript

I have created three collections because I want to be able to do filter search by tasks or users etc

My Firebase collection looks like this:

```
Collection 1 - (Users)
- username
- name

Collection 2 - (Tasks)
- taskname
- points

Collection 3 - (taskData)
- userId (id from users collection)
- taskId (id from task collection)
- timestamp
```

**React Typescript - Fetch collection data**

```
interface UserTask {
    id: String;
    taskId: String;
    userId: String;
    date: Date;
}


  const [userTasks, setUserTasks] = useState<UserTask[]>([]);


  const getTaskData = () => {
    const taskRef = firestore.collection('taskData');
    taskRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
      const taskData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data()
      }))
      console.log(taskData)
    })
  }
```

I am able to get the TaskData which has userId and TaskId but have not been able to "join" the tables and get Users.name and Tasks.taskname.I want to get a output like below, How do I do that?

```
{
  "taskName1": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "date": "12.01.2002"
    },
    {
      "name": "Maya",
      "date": "15.01.2002"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hanna",
      "date": "13.01.2003"
    }
  ],
  "taskName2": [
    {
      "name": "Maya",
      "date": "20.04.2003"
    },
    {
      "name": "Maya",
      "date": "17.06.2003"
    }
  ],
  "taskName3": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "date": "21.05.2003"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you are treating firebase like a SQL database, I suggest you put everything into one collection or use something like supabase.io

Comment: Indeed, Firestore has no join queries and allows you to read only from one collection at a time. As long as you have 3 collections, you'll need to query them individually and then work with the output. Similar questions have been asked on StackOverflow before: [link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65663943), [link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63632614).